# Entity reference views display with a contextual filter

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have this structure:
Organization - a simply content type.
Department - every department have an entity reference to an Organization.
User - every user have an entity reference to a Department.

When I (connected to 'Department 1(25)' in 'Pippo(8)' Organization) create a user i can have in my select list only the department of my organization.

I did not figure how to configure the contexual filter.

I setup a relationship between Department and Organization but how can i filter the organization to the logged user organization?